# Cannot assign - must be a "UserProfile" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I have a `class UserProfile` defined which takes the default `user` as a foreign key.
Now another `class A` has a foreign key to `UserProfile`.
So for saving any instance in class A, how do i give it the userprofile object.

Also, does making a `class UserProfile` mean that `class user` is still used and `class UserProfile` is just some other table?
I need to know this as I have to take care of the user profile creation, so I should know what gets stored where?

--
**Confused**

Comment: Should I create a foreign key to the `class user` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for saving any instance in class A,
>   how do i give it the userprofile
>   object.

1. Create a app with a model which has a `models.OneToOneField(User)` or a `models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)`.
2. Make your project aware of your UserProfile by pointing to it from the settings.py file `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'myapp.UserProfile'`.
3. Read the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

> Also, does making a class UserProfile
>   mean that class user is still used and
>   class UserProfile is just some other
>   table?

Yes, your database will have both a `auth_user` and a `user_profile` table. This is due to the fact that using UserProfiles doesn't mean all user have to have profiles. Only the additional fields defined in the `UserProfile` model will be in the `user_profile` table.

> I need to know this as I have to take
>   care of the user profile creation, so
>   I should know what gets stored where?

James Bennett created two nice apps which with a few hours of careful reading will be of great help especially when it comes to the user registration part. Go look at [django-registration](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) and [django-profiles](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/wiki/Home).

Comment: Thanks Simon. I just have one small doubt - So this means that the user auth can still be done using the normal user class as foreign key wherever required and I should not use the UserProfile class except when I am concerned with the "profiles"!

Comment: I think that this is a design question. If ALL users of your project have a profile you could always import the UserProfile, but I guess it's more common to only import the User to create reusable apps. In the first option your UserProfile becomes a dependency to all other apps and that might not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `UserProfile` model is intended to store additional information about your users. If so, there's [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) about the best approach to do this, which in brief is:

- define a model with fields for the additional information you'd like to store, or additional methods you'd like to have available, and also add a `OneToOneField` from your model to the User model. This will ensure only one instance of your model can be created for each User.
- Set [`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#setting-AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE) to `myapp.MyModel`, where `myapp` is the app containing the model `MyModel` which you want to use to store extra information about your users.

Comment: Yes, I have read that:
Two things -   
1. Does this stop using the `class user` (I have used a foreign key to the User model)  
2. Any other model which might require user information should ahve a foreign key just to the `class user` will this work? Or will the new model i set in AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE will take over? I hope I am clear. Thanks.